# How to run MongoDB as a single-node replica set using the official mongo Docker image?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, replicaset

Basically, the title already says it all: I would like to run MongoDB as a single-node replica set using the official mongo Docker image, but I don't get how to do this.

First of all, I have started the Docker image with the additional `--replSet "rs0"` parameter. Inside of the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` directory I have added a startup script, which runs:

```
rs.initiate();
```

However, no matter whether I provide options or not, MongoDB starts (and it seems to start successfully), but I am note able to connect to it using the Node.js MongoDB driver. If I set the `useUnifiedTopology` flag to `true`, nothing happens at all (connecting just hangs), if I set it to `false`, I get errors telling me that the connection timed out after 30 seconds.

Is there anything I am doing wrong fundamentally? Is it possible at all to run MongoDB as a replica set using the Docker image? Can anyone provide me some guidance?

## UPDATE 1

When I run the database as described above, and then run the following command:

```
$ docker exec -it test-mongo bash
```

And then inside the container I run:

```
$ mongo
```

I get connected to the database. I then run the following commands:

```
var database = db.getSiblingDB('test-db');
database.auth('user', 'password');
database.getCollectionNames();
```

The first two succeed without any problems, the third tells me that `listCollections` failed due to an uncaught exception with error message `not master and slaveOk=false`.

This sounds as if the single database server is not its own master, is it?

Comment: Can you connect with `mongo` shell?

Comment: See updated question.

Comment: What does `rs.status()` say ?

Comment: `not authorized on admin to execute command` … how do I authorize this command?

Comment: Take out authentication, get the replica set working, then put back auth.